# Electron npm package installtion failing on Linux OS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

I am trying to install electron npm package on Linux OS server with below command but it is failing

**npm install electron**

**Error as below :**

```
    # npm install electron
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/json-app/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/jsonapp/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:970:111)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/home/jsonapp/code/POC/json-app/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:43:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR!     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-15T07_19_23_981Z-debug-0.log
```

May I know the problem or any work around to install it successfully?

Thank you..

Comment: It looks like the mashine you run the command on, do not have access to the internet `RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com` or at least to dns server

Comment: @Seti, Yes I have internet access on it , bcoz I have installed npm on it successfully.

Comment: The message shows problems with connection